# There's "this" boy/girl/guy

Tags: demonstrative

Is the phrase "**there's this + *noun***" as in "*There's this girl I met yesterday ...*" a discourse marker?
If not, what is it considered to be in grammar terminology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There's this girl I met yesterday.

There is nothing non-standard about the use of *there's* here; the sentence would have much the same sense if it were spoken "There's **a** girl I met yesterday". What is unusual is specifically the use of *this*. *CGEL* (17.5.4(b), p. 1510) gives some examples:

> <sup>%</sup>*He's been married and got **this half-grown kid**.*
>  <sup>%</sup>*I was in Penang and I met **this man**, and he gave me your address and a present for you.*
>  <sup>%</sup>*She was wearing **these enormous earrings that she'd bought at the duty free**.*
>
> The demonstrative NPs here are **false definites** in that they have the form of a definite NP but do not satisfy the conditions for the felicitous use of one. They introduce new entities into the discourse and do not have sufficient descriptive content to identify the referent for the addressee. This usage is characteristic of very informal conversation, ...

I'd go a little further than *CGEL*. To me the colloquial *this* is not a false  *definite*—the speaker has a very particular kid, man, pair of earrings in mind, and usually the object indicated will have some further role in the discourse—but a false *reference*—the kid, man, pair of earrings are not present. But if they *were* present, the speaker could *and would* point them out with an ordinary *this*.

Comment: I agree with you regarding the "object in mind"- in the sense it makes sense! I had the same feeling about it, though I am not a grammarian nor a native speaker. They might argue it does not reference a direct real object in place, but I should stop here; it could get hairy! Oh, thank you.

Comment: StoneyB This brings to mind, *There's that man again*, when your interlocutor has no idea what man you are referencing and why you are referring to the man with *that.* So the usual response is *What man?*

Comment: @CarSmack But that looks to me like a deictic and locative *there* rather than an existential *there* - "There he is!"